# While executing a batch file (having multiple user inputs) from python, how can we handle / automate those user inputs inside python code?

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, user-input

Content of Batch file "input.bat" is:

```
ECHO off

SET /p id=ID:
SET /p pwd=Password:
SET /p email=Email:

ECHO Hello %id%, '%pwd%', "%email%" >> output.txt

:eof
```

Python script I wrote is:

```
import subprocess

inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c']
subprocess.Popen('input.bat',
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                 shell=True,
                 text=True).communicate('\n'.join(inputs))
```

The code is stuck forever.

Please help me rectifying the Python script.

Comment: I'd assume you need just one line in your batch file: ```@ECHO Hello %1, '%2', "%~3" 1>> "output.txt"```

Comment: My question was how to automate the bat file execution from python not change the bat file.

Comment: Your batch file requires changing! It is asking for interactive user input, whereby you are wanting to run a batch file which takes three arguments, `a`, `b`, and `c`. Your python script should therefore be running a batch file passing those three arguments to it. If you did need to ask interactively for the inputs before running the batch file, that should be performed in the far more advanced scripting language of python.